# Remove non-ascii characters from CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, non-ascii-characters

I'm querying a table in a SQL Server database and exporting out to a CSV using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
df.to_csv(csvFile, index=False)
```

Is there a way to remove non-ascii characters when exporting the CSV?

Comment: `df.to_csv(csvFile, index=False, encoding='ascii')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in the file and then use a regular expression to strip out non-ASCII characters:

```
df.to_csv(csvFile, index=False)

with open(csvFile) as f:
    new_text = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', f.read())

with open(csvFile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_text)
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response.  If you have time, is it possible to change the encoding of the CSV from ANSI to UTF-8?  I tried appending "encoding='utf-8'" to the second open function, but the CSV remains in ANSI

Comment: Hmm...well, I'm not really sure how to help with that. Perhaps the writing to the file (after the `to_csv` call) is the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

This was the case I ran into. Here's what worked for me:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+') #regex that matches non-ascii characters
with open(csvFile, 'r') as infile, open('myfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:  #keep looping until we hit EOF (meaning there's no more lines to read)
        outfile.write(regex.sub('', line)) #write the current line in the input file to the output file, but if it matches our regex then we replace it with nothing (so it will get removed)
```